# Redux + React how to change only one element value in array full of objects? I have working app, just want to make sure I do it right

Tags: reactjs, redux

Once again: I have items in redux store -> array which contains objects {id: str, val: bool}

I want to change obj value by id, I did it this way, it works but I think I over complicated:

```
export const setItems = items => {
   return {
       type: SET_DATA,
       payload: items
   }
}

export const changeItem = id => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let cpItems = getState().items.items.map( el => // creating copy
            id === el._id ? {...el, val: !el.val} : el
        )
        dispatch(setItems(cpItems)) //sending copy
    }
}
```

and reducer:

```
const itemsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case SET_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload
            }
        default: return state
    }
}
```

is this how is it done in redux ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is fine, and you can create actions that contain logic.

However, I would not use a thunk for a sync action. I would move the logic to the reducer, and create a specific action type for `changeItem`:

```
export const changeItem = id => ({
   type: CHANGE_ITEM,
   payload: id
})

const itemsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload
      }
    case CHANGE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.map(el => // creating copy
          id === el._id ? {...el, val: !el.val} : el
        )
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```